# Obtener el número de la columna de un valor que está dentro de un array bidimensional

Tags: java, processing

Estoy utilizando Processing 3 y en un array, `words`, que tiene como filas las 26 letras y como columnas tres idiomas. He hecho una búsqueda del elemento menor, por filas

```
for(int i = 1; i < words[0].length; i++){ 
  minor = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++){  
      minor = words[j][i]; 
      if(words[j][i] < minor){
        minor = words[i][j];
        idioma[i] = int(words[i][j]);        
      }        
    }
    println("el menor en fila "+i+" es "+minor+" y está en la columna "+???);    
  }
```

Quiero utilizar el valor de la columna donde está ese elemento `minor` de cada fila para rellenar un array definido así `int [] array = new int[26]`. Se agradecería cualquier sugerencia y ayuda.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner aunque sea un fragmento de ese arreglo y el output deseado? Es un poco difícil de entender así tu pregunta

Comment: Después del println("el menor de ...) puedes guardar minor en el nuevo arreglo: arrMinors[i]=minor; ¿Eso es lo que quieres? El arreglo guardoa os valores menores en la fila que le corresponde. Si quieres guardar la columna entonces utiliza otra variable parecida a minor ColMinor para guardar j. colMinor=j; Y guardas colMinor en el nuevo arrrglo